# Elevator puzzle

Tags: lateral-thinking

A guy lives in the 10th floor of an apartment building.
On a normal day he goes to the 5th floor with the elevator and then climbs the remaining 5 floors.
On a rainy day he goes to the 10th floor directly.

Why ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think:

> He is a short person, so he can't reach the button, when it's raining he has his umbrella to push the button for him

Comment: I was thinking about wet fire escapes but I like your version better!

Comment: yes its the correct answer is he is short

Comment: @Elgert, then you should mark answer as accepted.

Comment: Of course those who are so short as to suffer from an issue like this usually carry simple foldable 'reacher' to handle situations just like this.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility :

> He prefer to take the stairs instead of the elevator. On his building stairs start only on 5th floor, are outside and aren't protected of rain. When the weather is ok he stops on the 5th floor and takes the stairs, but when it's raining he prefer to be dry and go directly on his floor.

Comment: Stairs start on the 5th floor??  Is that a thing?

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of silly ... feel free do downvote this if you think this is too weird ._.

Comment: @dennisdeems Could be some explanations, like stairs are broken. Could be that he prefers to take the *outside* stairs, which could possibly start at 5. I remember when someone asked me a murder mystery like this, this was the first thing I thought of.